# Is there any Euler-Lagrange equation for functions dependent on only $x$ and $y$ and not on $y'$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am currently taking a class in which we are working on calculus of variations, but I was given the following problem:

A circular column of water of radius $l$ is rotated about its vertical axis atconstant angular velocity, $ω$, so that the surface is a radially symmetric function whose low point is at the center of the circular cross-section. The (upper) free surface assumes a shape which preserves the volume $$V=2\pi \int_{0}^{l} xy(x)dx$$

and minimizes the potential energy $$\rho \pi\int_0^l [gy^2(x)-\omega^2 x^2y(x)]xdx$$.

$ρ$ is the density of the water, g is the standard gravitational constant
and $y(x)$ is the height of the water at a radial distance $x$ from the center.

Now, I've looked at the 3 separate cases for applying the E-L equation, but as far as I know, they're only for $F(y'), F(x,y')$ and $F(y,y')$. Is there something I'm missing? Or any way to work out how to find $y(x)$, or minimize $\omega$?

Comment: The second formula is not an equation. And the first formula seems like a definition for $V$. Could you write exactly the problem that you were given?

Comment: @Andrei I've added the entire problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equation is still valid. In your case, the Lagrangian $\mathscr{L}$ is given by
$$\mathscr{L}(x, y, y')=\varrho \pi (gy^2-\omega^2x^2 y)+\lambda 2\pi x y$$
So the Euler-Lagrange equation is:
$$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial y}=0$$

Comment: OHH yes alright, this helped a lot, thank you!